# Find the increasing order of formation of ortho product

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, electrophilic-substitution

> [image]
>
> Find the increasing order of *ortho* product formation when Y is (i) F, (ii) Cl, (iii) Br, (iv) I.

We know that halides are *ortho*, *para* directing for EAS reactions and we consider the electronic stabilization effect as the reason for it. According to me, the order should be 1 > 2 > 3 > 4 because fluorine will give better electronic stabilization due to P(pi) – P(pi) bonding, and steric effect of iodine will reduce the amount of *ortho* product

But the answer given is 4 > 3 > 2 > 1.